# Android - Null Intent after declaring variables

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have two classes. The first one contains the following code:

```
Intent app=new Intent(context, NotificationButtonsHandler.class);
app.putExtra("DO", "app");
PendingIntent pApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, app, 0);
view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app, pApp);
```

And the other one contains the following code:

```
String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("DO");
if (action.equals("app")) {
    Intent app = new Intent(this, Resolution.class);
    startActivity(app);
}
```

By using the Intents from the first one I achieve to start an Activity at the second.
 Due to readability reasons I decided to modify the first class's source like this:

```
public static final String ACTION_NAME = "DO";
public static final String ACTION = "App";    
Intent app=new Intent(context, NotificationButtonsHandler.class);
app.putExtra(ACTION_NAME, ACTION);
PendingIntent pApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, app, 0);
view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app, pApp);
```

And the second one is modified like this:

```
String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(ClassA.ACTION_NAME);
//Even if I put here Log.e("ERROR", action); the compiler complains for NullPointerException
if (action.equals(ClassA.ACTION)) { //NullPointerException
    Intent app = new Intent(this, Resolution.class);
    startActivity(app);
}
```

The result of these modifications is a NullPointerException at the points specified at the second class.
 Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: I have found the solution of communicating between these two classes. The question is here for an academic conversation. I am trying to find out if this is an Android bug, or a bug of mine!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the static variables by using putExtra, so

```
app.putExtra(ACTION_NAME, ACTION);
```

and

```
String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(ClassA.ACTION_NAME);
```

both can be removed, just access your static variables directly using ClassA.ACTION_NAME and ClassA.ACTION

and i believe the real problem is here

change

```
String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(ClassA.ACTION_NAME);
```

to

```
String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(ACTION_NAME);
```

Comment: The PendingIntent comes from a Button which is in the notification area. This button wakes up my application's main screen. It is not possible to call the variable without Intents. Even if it was possible, how could I start my application?

Comment: The thing is that, you just don't pass a static variables around, if you really wanna pass data, dont use static, change it to regular strings then it should be working fine

Comment: `String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(ClassA.ACTION_NAME);` change to `String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(ACTION_NAME);` ?

Comment: To do this I have to create a new class using the class constructor. Why should I choose to load a new class in memory? What's the difference between a static String and a non-static when they are used in Intents? I am trying to understand why this is happening, not how to solve the problem neither a different way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are generating the `PendingIntent`. You've written:

```
PendingIntent pApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, app, 0);
```

If there is already a `PendingIntent` in the system with the same component (ie:  `NotificationButtonsHandler`), then this call will return the existing `PendingIntent`, which may or may not contain the extras that you want. To fix this you should create the `PendingIntent` like this:

```
PendingIntent pApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, app, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This will ensure that the call to retrieve the `PendingIntent` will actually replace the extras with the ones you provide.

Comment: Still it is not working. The only thing I can imagine is that the other class, which has the static fields, is garbage collected and after that action I cannot retrieve the static values.

Comment: Static fields are **never** garbage collected. They belong to the class and stay around until the class is unloaded (ie: never).

Comment: It is, however, possible that your process is being killed and that would clear (reinitialize) the static variables. You shouldn't expect to be able to keep stuff in static variables forever. If you need that kind of persistence, you need to store the values in a database, or a file, or in shared preferences.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint in `onCreate()` of your second activity. Then look at the `Intent` you are getting. You can also do this by adding logging to `onCreate()`. There is something else strange going on here.